# When buying an energy potion, does it permanently increase your energy?

Tags: bloons-td-battles

In Bloons TD Battles, you have the option to purchase energy potions which increase your energy by a certain amount, depending on the package you buy. My question is, is this change permanent? For example, if you buy the large energy potion, will your max energy increase by 50, or will it just give you 50 energy and then go back to normal once you have used all of your energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not permanently increase your energy capacity. It only adds to the 20 default that you are allocated. So for example, I had 20/20 energy before the purchase and afterward, I had 70/20. It does not automatically regenerate back up to 70.